# Error when installing scipy: "Broken toolchain"

Tags: scipy, pip

I am trying to install `scipy` on my windows 10 laptop.

When typing `pip install scipy` I am getting the following runtime error:

```
File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 675, in get_mathlib_info
raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

I have gone through all the related threads here on SO and they either didn't work or weren't possible to do on windows.

Comment: What is the question exactly, then? Hard to guess... In case you have Python 3.8. My advice would be to downgrade to Python 3.7, since 3.8 is really recent and doesn't have as broad a support as Python 3.7.

Comment: Thank you. This is what solved the problem. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. These days it is always the same question and the same answer. In a few months hopefully Python 3.8 will have broader support, and all these QAs will have no value whatsoever. Would you consider changing the title of your question to make it easier to find for people encountering a similar issue: "How to install scipy (1.3.1) on Python 3.8?" for example. And adapt the content of your question accordingly. I would then add a complete answer.

Comment: Installing scipy worked fine for me on win10/python3.8 - tried Christoph Gohlkes whl file? https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good advice is to downgrade to Python 3.7.

It seems like you are trying to install a project on Python 3.8. This version of Python is very recent and for this reason not all projects have been thoroughly tested against it and thus they might not even be easy to install on it to begin with.

Eventually retry in a few weeks or months with Python 3.8, by that time the maintainers of the project might have had time to do some more tests and might have improved the installation process on Python 3.8.

Installing the project on Python 3.8 today, might still be feasible but would most likely require much more effort, such as installing and configuring a build toolchain for the C/C++ extensions. Alternatively it might be worth checking out [Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), this 3rd party offers for pre-built wheel distributions for Windows exclusively.

Comment: I don't think this is a package issue, more likely, the OP's environment isn't configured correctly to build the package for Py3.8

Comment: Sure. In all similar questions I have seen so far, people are perfectly happy downgrading to Python 3.7 and take advantage of the pre-built wheels available on PyPI. They don't have any use for Python 3.8 specifically, or a full build toolchain that they wouldn't even know how to install or configure to begin with. They just want to use the project (scipy in this case) period.